# React button active style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I am new to React and UI development, please bear with me.
I have a list of buttons and I am trying to set different image icon when the button is active, and when I click on another button the second button should be active and first one de-active and so on.

Here is my code:

```
export class ABC extends Component {
    configFile = require('../../resources/stubs/config.json')

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cSelected: [],
            isHidden: true,
            level: this.configFile.Level,
            amount: this.configFile.amount,
            des1: this.configFile.desc1,
            des2: this.configFile.desc2,
            des3: this.configFile.desc3,

        }
        this.onRadioBtnClick = this.onRadioBtnClick.bind(this);
    };

    onRadioBtnClick(cSelected, aSelected, d1, d2, d3) {
        this.setState({
             cSelected,
             aSelected,
             d1,
             d2,
             d3
       });
    }



    render(){
        return (
          <div>
            <ButtonGroup>
                <Button className="circleIcon" 
                        onClick={() => this.onRadioBtnClick(this.state.level, this.state.amount, this.state.des1, this.state.des2, this.state.des3, )} 
                        active={this.state.cSelected === 1}><img src={incirclePurple}  
                        alt="profile-tab-icon" />|<span className="numberCircle">1</span></Button>
                <Button className="circleIcon" onClick={() => this.onRadioBtnClick("Circle2", "$1,000-$2,499", this.state.des1, this.state.des2, this.state.des3)} active={this.state.cSelected === 2}><img src={incirclePurple}  alt="profile-tab-icon" />|<span className="numberCircle">2</span></Button>
                <Button className="circleIcon" onClick={() => this.onRadioBtnClick("Circle3", "$2,500-$4,999", this.state.des1, this.state.des2, this.state.des3)} active={this.state.cSelected === 3}><img src={incirclePurple}  alt="profile-tab-icon" />|<span className="numberCircle">3</span></Button>
                <Button className="circleIcon" onClick={() => this.onRadioBtnClick("Circle4", "$5,000-$9,999", this.state.des1, this.state.des2, this.state.des3)} active={this.state.cSelected === 4}><img src={incirclePurple}  alt="profile-tab-icon" />|<span className="numberCircle">4</span></Button>
                <Button className="circleIcon" onClick={() => this.onRadioBtnClick("Circle5", "$10,000-$34,999", this.state.des1, this.state.des2, this.state.des3)} active={this.state.cSelected === 5}><img src={incirclePurple}  alt="profile-tab-icon" />|<span className="numberCircle">5</span></Button>
                <Button className="circleIcon" onClick={() => this.onRadioBtnClick("Circle6", "$35,000-$74,999", this.state.des1, this.state.des2, this.state.des3)} active={this.state.cSelected === 6}><img src={incirclePurple}  alt="profile-tab-icon" />|<span className="numberCircle">6</span></Button>
                <Button className="circleIcon" onClick={() => this.onRadioBtnClick("President's Circle", ">$74,999", this.state.des1, this.state.des2, this.state.des3)} active={this.state.cSelected === 7}><img src={incirclePurple}  alt="profile-tab-icon" />|<span className="numberCircle">7</span></Button>
                <Button className="circleIcon" onClick={() => this.onRadioBtnClick("Chairman's Circle", ">$74,999", this.state.des1, this.state.des2, this.state.des3)} active={this.state.cSelected === 8}><img src={incirclePurple}  alt="profile-tab-icon" />|<span className="numberCircle">8</span></Button>
            </ButtonGroup>   
            <div>
                <p>{this.state.cSelected}{this.state.aSelected}</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>{this.state.d1}</li>
                    <li>{this.state.d2}</li>
                    <li>{this.state.d3}</li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
        </div>) 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give a unique `name` prop for each button and create a `activeButton` state which will take the value of the activated button name:

```
handleActiveButton(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const activeName = e.target.name;
  this.setState({ activeName });
}
```

Then in `className` prop of your buttons, you could do something like `className={ this.state.activeName === 'button1' ? 'active' : '' }`

Where `button1` is the name of the button, and `active` is your css class to display your image icon.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Nenu!! I really appreciate it. I am sorry if this is a stupid question, but I added the event on my button.

Comment: <ButtonGroup>
                          <Button className={this.state.activeName === "1" ? 'active':'circleIcon' } name="1" onClick={(event) => this.onRadioBtnClick(event, this.state.data[0].Level, this.state.data[0].amount, this.state.data[0].desc1, this.state.data[0].desc2, this.state.data[0].desc3)} active={this.state.cSelected === "1"}><img src={this.state.incircleImage}  alt="profile-tab-icon" />|<span className="numberCircle">1</span></Button>
                          
                        </ButtonGroup>

Comment: and tried to setState activeName:::                                                                   onRadioBtnClick(e, cSelected, aSelected, d1, d2, d3 ) {
    this.setState({ cSelected, aSelected, d1, d2, d3 });
    e.preventDefault();
    const activeName = e.target.name;
    console.log("activeName ="+ activeName);
    this.setState({ activeName });
  }                                                                     I am getting undefined for e.target.name.                                  I hope I am not making some horrible mistake. Thank again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!

Populated the value of activeName through id

Thanks!!